# Web Scraping with Beautifulsoup python - cannot scrap all results

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i tried to scrap data from this site

https://www.nobroker.in/property/sale/chennai/Adyar?searchParam=W3sibGF0IjoxMy4wMDExNzc0LCJsb24iOjgwLjI1NjQ5NTcsInBsYWNlSWQiOiJDaElKZ1JiRUZlMW5Vam9SZzU0a2VwYk9hV1UiLCJwbGFjZU5hbWUiOiJBZHlhciJ9XQ==&radius=2.0&city=chennai&locality=Adyar

i used the following code

\\

```
import pandas as pd
from requests import get as gt
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs


def nobroker(url):


house_title = []
location=[]
area=[]
emi=[]
price=[]

p = gt(url)
b = bs(p.content)


for i in b.find_all('span',class_="overflow-hidden overflow-ellipsis whitespace-nowrap max-w-80pe po:max-w-full"):
    house_title.append(i.text)
 
for i in b.find_all('div',class_="mt-0.5p overflow-hidden overflow-ellipsis whitespace-nowrap max-w-70 text-gray-light leading-4 po:mb-0 po:max-w-95"):
    location.append(i.text)


for i in b.find_all('div',class_="p-1.5p flex border-b border-b-solid border-cardbordercolor tp:py-1p tp:px-1.5p tp:border-b-0"):
    area.append(i.text.split("₹")[1].replace("sqftBuiltup",""))


for i in b.find_all('div',class_="p-1.5p flex border-b border-b-solid border-cardbordercolor tp:py-1p tp:px-1.5p tp:border-b-0"):
    emi.append(i.text.split("₹")[2].replace("/MonthEstimated EMI",""))  



for i in b.find_all('div',class_="p-1.5p flex border-b border-b-solid border-cardbordercolor tp:py-1p tp:px-1.5p tp:border-b-0"):
    price.append(i.text.split("₹")[3])  


df = pd.DataFrame({"Name of House":house_title,"Location":location,"Area":area,"EMI":emi,"Price":price})


return df
```

\\

but its only getting 4 results data only. but in actual website has more than 100 results. why i cannot scrap all data from this site.

Comment: can you fix the indentation first?

Comment: Website probably using JavaScript to load the rest. Use JavaScript driven engines like selenium https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you see is loaded from external source via JavaScript. You can use their API to get the data. For example:

```py
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd


api_url = "https://www.nobroker.in/api/v1/multi/property/sale/filter"

query = {
    "pageNo": 0,
    "searchParam": "W3sibGF0IjoxMy4wMDExNzc0LCJsb24iOjgwLjI1NjQ5NTcsInBsYWNlSWQiOiJDaElKZ1JiRUZlMW5Vam9SZzU0a2VwYk9hV1UiLCJwbGFjZU5hbWUiOiJBZHlhciJ9XQ==",
    "radius": "2.0",
    "city": ["chennai", "chennai"],
    "locality": "Adyar",
}


all_data, page = [], 0
while True:
    print("Getting page. {}".format(page))
    query["pageNo"] = page
    data = requests.get(api_url, params=query).json()

    if not data["data"]:
        break

    # uncomment this to print all data:
    # print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

    for p in data["data"]:
        all_data.append(
            {
                "house_title": p["propertyTitle"],
                "location": p["locality"],
                "emi": p["defaultEmi"],
                "price": p["price"],
            }
        )

    page += 1

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
print(df)
df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

Prints:

```
                                                                                                          house_title                                                                      location              emi      price
0                                                                2 BHK Flat  For Sale  In Vasanth Apartments In Adyar                                                                         Adyar     57,314/Month   10000000
1                                                                              2 BHK Flat  For Sale  In Rams In Adyar                                                                         Adyar     63,045/Month   11000000
2                                                               3 BHK In Independent House  For Sale  In Besant Nagar                                                                  Besant Nagar  1.43 Lacs/Month   25000000


...
```

and saves `data.csv` (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]

Comment: thanks for your help code is working perfectly but i have a noob question how did you find the website is using java script to get data and also how can i find a website api and params

Comment: @Manivannan In your code if you do `print(b)` you see that all the info isn't there. The page must then load the info from elsewhere (usually with the help of JavaScript)